SFTP client with key authentication with passphrase using Apache MINA?
I am trying to write an SFTP client using Apache MINA sshd-sftp package.
Client should use key authentication and the key is encrypted using a passphrase.
The documentation mentions to created key pairs.
KeyPairResourceLoader loader = SecurityUtils.getKeyPairResourceParser();
Collection<KeyPair> keys = loader.loadKeyPairs(null, filePath, passwordProvider);

and set keys in session using
try (ClientSession session = ...estblish initial session...) {
    for (KeyPair kp : keys) {
        session.addKeyIdentity(kp);
    }
    
    session.auth().await(...);
}

For  private key files that are encrypted, FilePasswordProvider needs to be passed.
FilePasswordProvider is an interface. How to create FilePasswordProvider?
Thanks

The FilePasswordProvider interface has single non-default method FilePasswordProvider.getPassword.
So it should be possible to implement the interface using lambda, like this:
FilePasswordProvider myPasswordProvider =
    (session, resourceKey, retryIndex) -> "mypassword";

